# Writing cross-compatible Python 2/3: Difference between __future__, six, and future.utils?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, six

I'm writing cross-compatible Python 2 and 3 code with some help from this [cheatsheet](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html). I've noticed there are different packages and modules that help to do this: the `future` package (e.g. `future.utils` etc), the `six` package, and the built in `__future__` module.

Are there any differences to be aware of when using these packages? Should I be mixing and matching them, or is it possible to write fully cross-compatible code be written with just one of them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In terms of python 2-3 compatibility:

`__future__` - is a built-in module in python which allows you to use optional features in python versions where they are optional (vs mandatory). For example, `unicode_literals` was optional in `python2.7` but became mandatory in `python3.0`.

`six` - mostly renames modules/functions to produce higher compatibility between `python2` to `python3`, but doesn't actually backport (or forward-port) functionality. It is also supported for python versions `>=2.4`.

`future` - more modern, only supports `python>=2.6,>=3.3`, and is more rich in features.

Seems like [there is some agreement](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) that `future` is preferred to `six` if you can drop support for old versions of python.